# e4 RCP: modifying main-menu item programmatically

Tags: eclipse, menuitem, e4

I would like to add/remove an icon to some menu items in my application.
This is easy if I click on the item itself because I can inject a reference into the handler:

```
@Execute
public void execute(MMenuItem menuItem) {
    //add icon to menuItem
}
```

But my question is: how do I do this from the outside if I only have got its id?

Comment: Okay, I could do this by using `DynamicMenuContribution`s. But I am curious, if I can also access existing "normal" `HandledMenuItem`s.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `EModelService` to find the element:

```java
@Inject
EModelService modelService;
@Inject
MApplication application;

List<MMenuItem> list = modelService.findElements(app, "menu item id", MMenuItem.class, 
                      Collections.emptyList(), EModelService.IN_MAIN_MENU);
```

Comment: Okay, I guess I know where my problem is: I am using Eclipse 4.3. Apparently this used to be a bug: [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383403). Do you know any other good way how to get the menu item?

Comment: If you are doing e4 development I would suggest that you should be using 4.4 for the general bug fixes and improvements.

Comment: @greg-449 the Model service always returns null for menus or menu items of the main shell for me. I have tried calling it in my APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE handler of the lifecycle manager of my app, to no avail. Also cannot retrieve the menu object itself (id: "menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu"). Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you need to the 'findElements' call of modelService with the EModelService.IN_MAIN_MENU option to search menu items. Revised answer to show the call.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Greg, had missed this flag.